# Attach circle to svg circle dash

Tags: svg

I need to attach a circle to the end of a svg circle dash as shown on the pic below. Could make the dash beginning and end on http://jsfiddle.net/q3wb6gkq/ round with `stroke-linecap="round"`. Now how do I go about attaching a circle to its end?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the svg I'm adding a small circle for the thumb.

I'm calculating the position of the last point of the dash on the circle using `getPointAtLength`.

I'm setting the values of the cx and cy attributes of the thumb using `setAttribute`

Please observe that I'm wrapping both the circle and the thumb in a group `<g>` and apply the transformation to the group.

```js
//the value of the stroke-dasharray attribute
let sda = Number(c.getAttribute("stroke-dasharray"));
//the value of the stroke-dashoffset attribute
let sdo = Number(c.getAttribute("stroke-dashoffset"));

let l = sda - sdo;
//get the position of a point at the end of the dash
let p = c.getPointAtLength(l);
//set the values of the cx and cy attributes of the `#thumb` circle
thumb.setAttribute("cx",p.x);
thumb.setAttribute("cy",p.y);
```

```html
<svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g  transform="rotate(270, 80, 80)">
    <circle id="c" r="70" cy="80" cx="80" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="440" stroke-dashoffset="150" />
    <circle id="thumb" fill="red" r="6" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you much. I've got a solution and learned about svgs. Now will adapt it to use in a React component.